# Multiple implementations for the same trait of the same type in Rust

Tags: rust, traits, typeclass

With Rust traits, I can express a `Monoid` type class (forgive me for the naming of the methods):

```rust
trait Monoid {
  fn append(self, other: Self) -> Self;
  fn neutral() -> Self;
}
```

Then, I can also implement the trait for strings or integers:

```rust
impl Monoid for i32 {
  fn append(self, other: i32) -> i32 {
    self + other
  }
  fn neutral() -> Self { 0 }
}
```

However, how could I now add another implementation on `i32` for the multiplication case?

```rust
impl Monoid for i32 {
  fn append(self, other: i32) -> i32 {
    self * other
  }
  fn neutral() { 1 }
}
```

I tried something like what is done in [functional](https://docs.rs/crate/functional/0.0.7) but that solution seems to rely on having an additional type parameter on the trait instead of using `Self` for the elements, which gives me a warning.

The preferred solution would be using marker traits for the operations - something I also tried but didn't succeed in.

Comment: I don't understand what this is supposed to represent. How is the compiler supposed to guess which implementation you want if both have exactly the same signatures?

Comment: You are right. I would like to find out, whether there is a way to use something like marker traits as additional type parameters or something the like to let the compiler distinguish the two cases.

Comment: @Yann, about my post: Yes, but the case with the trait constrains is different. Since a type could implement just one of them. The trait constrains should be enough for him to realise it is 2 different implementations. And in case a type implement both mul and add, then you can disambiguate it explicitly in use.... I don't know why it cannot infer that they are 2 different implementations.

Comment: You can use a marker type such as in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e0d2d44c8b11f148458f0116a750364). Is that what you want?

Comment: @rodrigo Awesome, that looks very much like what I wanted. I could also add a common trait `Op` that both operation structs implement ([here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69040846dafcf9ed9f3b0c58c8199f50)). Thanks!

Comment: @Yann: Nice! Now that you have a working code, feel free to answer (and eventually accept) your own question,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer, as pointed out by @rodrigo, is to use *marker structs*.

The following example shows a working snippet: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69040846dafcf9ed9f3b0c58c8199f50)

```rust
trait Op {}
struct Add;
struct Mul;
impl Op for Add {}
impl Op for Mul {}

trait Monoid<T: Op>: Copy {
    fn append(self, other: Self) -> Self;
    fn neutral() -> Self;
}

impl Monoid<Add> for i32 {
    fn append(self, other: i32) -> i32 {
        self + other
    }
    fn neutral() -> Self {
        0
    }
}

impl Monoid<Mul> for i32 {
    fn append(self, other: i32) -> i32 {
        self * other
    }
    fn neutral() -> Self {
        1
    }
}

pub enum List<T> {
    Nil,
    Cons(T, Box<List<T>>),
}

fn combine<O: Op, T: Monoid<O>>(l: &List<T>) -> T {
    match l {
        List::Nil => <T as Monoid<O>>::neutral(),
        List::Cons(h, t) => h.append(combine(&*t)),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let list = List::Cons(
        5,
        Box::new(List::Cons(
            2,
            Box::new(List::Cons(
                4,
                Box::new(List::Cons(
                    5,
                    Box::new(List::Cons(-1, Box::new(List::Cons(8, Box::new(List::Nil))))),
                )),
            )),
        )),
    );
    
    println!("{}", combine::<Add, _>(&list));
    println!("{}", combine::<Mul, _>(&list))
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to read, is there a better way of doing this?