# Struct that is hashed and sorted via different fields (requiring different Eq implementation)

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a struct

```
struct Obj {
    id: i32,
    value: i64,
}
```

that can be used in a `BinaryHeap` and a `HashSet`.

When used with the `BinaryHeap`, I want it to be ordered based on `value`.
When used with `HashSet`, I want it to be hashed with `id`.

Both of these require an implementation of the `Eq` trait but I can't find a way to have two different implementations of `Eq`.

The closest I found was [Multiple implementations for the same trait of the same type in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832862/multiple-implementations-for-the-same-trait-of-the-same-type-in-rust) but this seems to only work if  the trait accepts a generic argument which isn't the case for `Eq`

Comment: The standard way of achieving this is by defining a trivial zero-cost wrapper around your struct. In this case, you could define a `HeapObj` that implements `Ord` suitable for use in `BinaryHeap`, and a `SetObj` that implements `Eq` suitable for use in a `HashSet`. For example: https://pastebin.com/eqz4KAnU

Comment: Also consider the [`binary-heap-plus` crate](https://crates.io/crates/binary-heap-plus) that allows specifying a key function separately from the value being put into the heap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do not do this**. In Rust `Hash` and `Eq` implementations must align with each other. Documentation of [Hash](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html#hash-and-eq) trait specifically says:

> When implementing both Hash and Eq, it is important that the following property holds:
>
> ```
> k1 == k2 -> hash(k1) == hash(k2)
> ```
>
> In other words, if two keys are equal, their hashes must also be equal. HashMap and HashSet both rely on this behavior.
>
> Thankfully, you won’t need to worry about upholding this property when deriving both Eq and Hash with #[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)].
>
> **Violating this property is a logic error**. The behavior resulting from a logic error is not specified, but users of the trait must ensure that such logic errors do not result in undefined behavior. This means that unsafe code must not rely on the correctness of these methods.

Use *newtype* pattern to create two types that implement `Hash` and `Eq` differently and use them as elements for `HashMap` and `BinaryHeap`.

```rust
struct Obj {
    id: i32,
    value: i64,
}

// implement `Hash` that will hash `self.0.id`.
struct ObjHash(Obj);

// implement `Eq` that will compare `self.0.value`.
struct ObjEq(Obj);

fn foo() {
    let hash_map: HashMap<ObjHash> = todo!();
    let bin_heap: BinaryHeap<ObjEq> = todo!();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need two separate versions of `[Partial]Eq`? As far as I can tell, in your case it would be fine to derive `PartialEq, Eq` and implement `Hash` and `[Partial]Ord` manually. In fact, if you reorder the fields `id` and `value` in the struct definition, you can derive everything but `Hash` and then just manually implement `Hash` to only take `id` into consideration. This would not break the rule that equality of objects implies equality of their hashes. (`PartialOrd` will additionally take `id` into account, but surely that's not a problem?)